--pyi_out: protoc-gen-pyi: Plugin failed with status code 1
I'm trying to run this command in docker:
RUN python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I ./ --python_out=. --pyi_out=. --grpc_python_out=. my.proto

and seeing this error:
0.423 protoc-gen-pyi: program not found or is not executable
0.423 Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
0.423 --pyi_out: protoc-gen-pyi: Plugin failed with status code 1.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -c python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I ./ --python_out=. --pyi_out=. --grpc_python_out=. my.proto" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

why this is happening and how to solve it?

Please include a minimal repro of your issue. I created my own minimal repro using docker.io/python:3.11.9-alpine3.19 image and was able to compile a protobuf without issue using your command.

Protoc is outdated in the Ubuntu repository.
I needed to use v25, instead of v3, so I ended up using a recent binary directly from https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases
